# Placing Code Into Separate Files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, file, external

An application I am working on is becoming pretty large (code wise) and I would love to find a way to tidy this up. I have searched everywhere but cannot find a solution that would help.

In the following example, I have a button click event.

```
        If newestversion.Contains(currentversion) Then
        Label4.Text = "You have the latest version"
        Label4.ForeColor = Color.Green
        BtnUpdate.Visible = False
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.happy_face
    Else
        Label4.Text = "New Version Available!"
        Label4.ForeColor = Color.Red
        BtnUpdate.Visible = True
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.sad_face
    End If
```

What I would love to do is something like this:

```
    Private Sub btnDefAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDefAdd.Click
'Link code from external file

        End If End Sub
```

The problem obviously is trying to work out how this can be done, if at all.
Anyone got any ideas or able to point me in the right direction?
Thanks
Dan

Comment: one option would be use partial classes to split your code, so that your implementation code is in a method in another file and is called from the event handler, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350.aspx

Comment: Split your application into tiered classes. Gui. DB. Security. Are you concerned about the compiled size or the size of each code file? Assuming all the coded features are required, I wouldn't expect either to be a consideration.

Comment: @Mort Yeah it's just to make editing easier etc. At the moment there is like 500 lines of code and I am only half way there. I just want to create a separate file for each section so they are easier to find and edit when needed.

Comment: @PhillipTrelford I have tried that but finding it hard to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment to your question, one option is to split the code into files using VB.Net's [partial class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514141.aspx) support.

First make your form class partial:

```
Partial Public Class Form1
```

Next create a new class file, called say Form1Impl, to put the code you want to separate in:

```
Partial Public Class Form1

    Sub HandleDefAdd()
        If newestversion.Contains(currentversion) Then
            Label4.Text = "You have the latest version"
            Label4.ForeColor = Color.Green
            BtnUpdate.Visible = False
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.happy_face
        Else
            Label4.Text = "New Version Available!"
            Label4.ForeColor = Color.Red
            BtnUpdate.Visible = True
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.sad_face
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now you can call the handler implementation from your event handler as if it were in the same file:

```
Private Sub BtnDefAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDefAdd.Click
    HandleDefAdd()
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried that Phillip. In the Class file, anything I put in there is not getting Declared.

Comment: @user3719039 sorry to hear that, it worked for me, check that both classes are marked partial and have the same name (not the name given by the editor)

Comment: It works! I don't know why it wouldn't yesterday but it works now. LOL Thanks so much Phillip. Really appreciate it. Will save me heaps of time. :)